# Non-US tax from Appstore earnings?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Does Apple "withhold a part of the  earnings for tax purposes" even for non-US developers? I've seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124093/tax-on-iphone-developer-payments) but it's not clear what happens to non-US developers. There's a reference to a form "W-8BEN" but I don't understand it -- is this what I have to fill out when I'm non-US and I want to avoid Apple to withhold the tax?

I know for instance earnings from [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) referral reward programs are only taxed for US citizens -- it is explicitly stated that for non-US people the full reward is paid out and they must handle the tax issue themselves. It's this kind of explicit statement that I'm looking for regarding earnings from the app store.

Comment: You should really talk to an accountant.

Comment: I don't understand why this is off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A W8BEN form allows a non-US company to declare that the US should not withhold taxes. A valid reason must be supplied. In ours we simple state the section of the NAFTA treaty that applies to cross border trade (part II, #10: "Article VII", "0%", for type of income "software license", reason "Corporation is a resident of Canada.")

Never had a problem getting full payment once the form has been filed with the customer.

Frankly it's a bit annoying but we've gotten used to it (and the form doesn't need to be customized, just recently dated).

Basically all Apple is looking for is the paper work so they can check the "0% withholding tax" checkbox in their accounts payable system.

Answer (score 8):

Passing on an answer from a friend (hi Glen) - this is the Australian perspective.

You should read the W-8BEN Tip Sheet downloadable from the Manage Your Tax Information screen in iTunesConnect. In particular, you don't need an ITIN as a Australian company/sole trader. Apply for the EIN instead using the provided SS-4 and fax it to the number given. You should get back the EIN details from the IRS in a couple of days. I received the number in 4 days from the fax and I think they also mailed me a letter in confirmation. You can then use the EIN to fill in Apple's documentation.

The other thing you should note is the Japanese tax form. If you expect decent Japanese sales e.g. if you've localized the content for Japan, then not filling in this form will lose you 20% of sales to withholding tax. Moreover because of the exchange rate etc. fixed at the time of the App Store opening, you actually get more per seat in Japanese sales than anywhere else. It takes 90 days for them to process this so the sooner you send it out, the better. I waited too long because I found some sections confusing but after checking with the iTunesConnect people it was actually quite straightforward.

Comment: This is all spot on, although I called the IRS directly. It took less than 10 minutes and I got the EIN straight away. You fill in the form, and the person on the other end will ask you to read out your answers to the questions. It was a lot less painful than I thought it would be.

Comment: Also, from an Australian perspective, it looks like Apple will collect the GST for you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, Apple collect the GST for you? Australians don't charge GST to non-Australian sales or are you just talking about the Australian App Store? If you make royalty income from other countries, I'd expect that to be GST-free.

Comment: For sales in Australia, Apple seem to withhold the GST on your behalf.

Comment: Ah - I assume the agreement is on gross price - you are getting a percentage of gross, where the consumer is charged gross+gst. However, if you are a GST-registered entity, you should probably treat 1/11th of what Apple remit you as being GST which you are obliged to pass on in turn to the ATO.

Comment: Do you really need an EIN though? The W-8BEN-E that iTunes Connect now guides you through seems to suggest that an EIN isn't required for an Australian company, and you can just put your foreign TIN in instead (my accountant and a lot of others have suggested putting your ABN there instead of your TFN).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be [in contact](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/store/) [with Apple](http://www.apple.com/contact/), instead of Stack Overflow.

*edit:* I assume that someone thinks that asking Apple directly is something you shouldn't do, since I got a downvote ;)

Comment: I thought it suitable to post the question here as many other people would also benefit from the answer. Plus it is useful to hear people's first-hand experiences too.

Comment: In my experience, Apple refused to provide any answers or hints regarding the forms as they considered it a tax advice which they told me I'd have to get from my attorney. So I don't think talking to Apple is an option here.

Comment: I asked Apple a question about the tax form, and they answered, "Because everyone's tax situation is unique to them, please consult with your tax advisor." Which is annoying, since APPLE is the one demanding this form be filled out, not my tax advisor.